# Selenuim.web_driver не видит элемент страницы

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Пытаюсь через selenuim.web_driver пройти регистрацию на сайте.

через driver.get(url) я попадаю на сайт. Там появляется accept cookies. Принимаю.

`cookies_accept = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()`

Дальше пытаюсь найти элемент для ввода логина. Нашел class в html коде.
Но selenium выводит ошибку, что такой элемент не найден.

```
try:
  driver.get('https://visa.vfsglobal.com/rus/en/fra/login')
  time.sleep(5)
  cookies_accept = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click()
  time.sleep(10)

  email_input =  driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c64-0")
```

при этом page_source выводит совершенно другой html код.